# How to add "show preview" button to VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I have a VS Code extension that analyses custom JSON and YAML files. So in the project's `package.json`, there is this:

```
    "activationEvents": [
        "onLanguage:yaml",
        "onLanguage:json",
        "onCommand:extension.sidePreview"
    ],
```

Whenever someone opens one of these files, I'd like to add a "show preview" icon in the top right corner of the editor:

[image: preview]

So I added the corresponding `icon` resources to the project, and:

```
"contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "extension.sidePreview",
                "title": "Preview file",
                "icon": {
                    "dark": "./resources/open-preview-dark.svg",
                    "light": "./resources/open-preview-light.svg"
                }
            }
        ],
        "menus": {
            "editor/title": [
                {
                    "command": "extension.sidePreview",
                    "when": "true"
                }
            ]
        },
```

But this doesn't work... I don't see any icon.

I'd also like to ensure that this button and command are only available when my function `isCustomFile` in `server.ts` returns `true`. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you added the wrong section under `menus`.

You are supposed to add `editor/title` instead.

[Reference](https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/blob/128.0.0/package.json#L238)

Comment: Hey, thanks! Now I see the command but not the icon :/ i pasted what I have in the question

Comment: Oh I had to add `group: navigation`!